# Fixing 'Import [module] could not be resolved' in pyright

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, pyright

I'm using pyright for type checking and I'm also using pytest for testing inside Visual Studio Code. The folder structure for my tests is to have a 'test' subfolder in the package root . For example

```
|
MyPackage
|-- __init__.py
|-- MyModule.py
|--test
   |-- __init__.py
   |--MyModule_test.py
```

I'm organizing things like this as there will be many packages and I want to keep things organized. 
Inside pytest I have

```py
import pytest
import MyPackage.MyModule 
...
```

Pytest is able to discover the tests and run them OK because it has some special ability to adjust its `sys.path` (or something).
However, pyright will just complain that it cannot import the module,
`Import 'MyPackage.MyModule' could not be resolvedpyright (reportMissingImports)`. This makes sense, but is there some way to deal with this, either in pyright or in the Visual Studio Code settings to stop this from complaining?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a `pyrightconfig.json` file or `pyproject.toml` file at the root of your project. For example, if it's a Django project, you should have one of those files where `manage.py` is placed. Then, set `include` parameter and add the subdirectories (or app folders in Django terms).

You can consult this [sample config file](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#sample-config-file). See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3378) issue ticket.

For example, if this were my project structure:

```
├── manage.py
├── movie
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── moviereviews
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── pyproject.toml
```

my `pyproject.toml` would be:

```
[tool.pyright]
include = ["movie", "moviereviews"]
```

If you are working within a Python virtual environment, set venvPath and venv. Consult the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md) for an exhaustive list of options.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, a relative import as illustrated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=relative%20import) was able to solve this. So in my case I should have

```py
# MyModule_test.py

import pytest
from .. import MyModule
```

Comment: I have the same problem but I can't use what you have. I have a statement like this in my pytest test file: `from quendor.zmachine.header import StoryHeader` This works fine in that PyTest can handle the import. Pyright refuses to find it. And a relative import doesn't work at all, unfortunately. My only solution has been to disable Pyright.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the library path to the path variable.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, str('..'))
import MyModule
```

To enable Pylance to use your library properly (for auto-complete ...), use the following steps:

Pylance, by default, includes the root path of your workspace. If you want to include other subdirectories as import resolution paths, you can add them using the `python.analysis.extraPaths` setting for the workspace.

1. In VS Code press "ctrl" + "," keys to open Settings.
2. Type in `python.analysis.extraPaths`
3. Select "Add Item"
4. Type in the path to your library `..'

Comment: Thanks for `python.analysis.extraPaths`. That helped me to solve my problem with imports.

Comment: It's a question about Pyright, not Pylance, sys.path.append/insert doesn't solve the issue.