# Discord.py ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, discord.py

TLDR: I've been trying to use discord.py on my mac for a while, but everything I've tried doesnt work. All the other solutions dont work!

Please help. I've been trying to get Discord.py to work for months now, and I can't get it to work. Here's my code [I'll reset my token, obviously]:

```
import discord


class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')


client = MyClient()


client.run("NzQxNzUzMTQ0MDA2MTQ4MTU2.Xy8Jcg.wBNInfNrj--ZtinuzQ-b4I7H1jo")
```

Which results in the folowing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 529, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 189, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 944, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/python_bot.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.run("NzQxNzUzMTQ0MDA2MTQ4MTU2.Xy8Jcg.wBNInfNrj--ZtinuzQ-b4I7H1jo")
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 291, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 185, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 858, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Users/meow/programming/PycharmProjects/BulmeniBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 938, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm on mac, using python 3.8 with Pycharm.

### What I have tried:

After some Googling, I got to [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/4159) thread, which in turn led me [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/423#issuecomment-272093801). Double clicking on `Install Certificates.command` gives me this error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8', '-E', '-s', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'certifi']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

After some more googling, that lead me to [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue36340) thread, which doesnt tell me anything since I'm just using my terminal. :(

I've tried `pip install --upgrade certifi` too, but the errors still remains. So what do I do?

Comment: Remove your token from `client.run(token)`, it allows anyone to run a bot under your bot's account. You need to regenerate that token in the developer portal under your application's `Bot` section and use that instead. Please make sure you scrub your files of this token before posting it anywhere or store it in a separate file (.env perhaps) and reference that whenever you need your token.

Comment: Yes, I already regenerated my token. I didn't take it out because I was scared I would delete something important. Thank you for the concern, though.

Comment: what error are you getting from `pip install`?  (perhaps try `pip3.8 install` to make sure you're updating the correct version of python.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant that pip install doesn't casue any errors, but the code still doesn't work. I tried that, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

On a mac, go to Macintosh HD > Applications > Python3.x folder (x being your python3 version) > double click on "Install Certificates.command" file

Answer (score 0):

Try both of these (Windows):

---

**Method #1:**
Download and install this certificate here: https://crt.sh/?id=2835394
It can be installed by double clicking the file and installing it to Local Computer.
[image: Image taken from a discord server]
If you are curious what caused this: https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA03l00000117LT
*Info taken from a discord server*

---

**Method #2:**

Navigate to your `Applications/Python 3.X/` folder and double click the `Install Certificates.command` to fix this.