# How to download discord.py and python on mac

Tags: python, macos, discord.py

I have downloaded discord.py and python before but it doesn't work for like the import discord command. And i need this command so that i can make my first discord bot. I have been using repl.it temporarily but i don't like the ui and repl.it always restarts which makes my work 2x times more slower.

Comment: Have you done [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#installing)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi take a look here for discord.py
https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/

And here for python for Mac

https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/

Regards Matthias

Answer (score 0):

1. you can install Python using brew, which is very easy
   Run the below command to do so :-

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```
2. Install Python using brew:-

   ```
   brew install python
   ```
3. Pip should be installed along with Python. You can upgrade it by below command (if not already upgraded) : -

   ```
   pip install --upgrade pip
   ```
4. Installing discord.py

   Python 3.5.3 or higher is required

   To install the library without full voice support, you can just run the following command:

   Linux/macOS

   ```
   python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
   ```

   Windows

   ```
   py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
   ```

   **Otherwise to get voice support you should run the following command:**

   Linux/macOS

   ```
   python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"
   ```

   Windows

   ```
   py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
   ```

I would suggest you create a virtual environment and play around with it.

Comment: Ty for the help. I found a solution which fixed my problem. In this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776601/discord-py-ssl-sslcertverificationerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed

Comment: nps at all :) Happy to help. Do upvote if you feel the answer was of help