# Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance

Tags: python, numpy

I have wrote the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel("X-axis")
plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
plt.title("graph of $x^2$")
plt.show()
```

When I run the code, it shows the following error:

[image]

I have installed NumPy, successfully, but still getting this warning. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: do you have multiple pythons or python environments? you can tell vscode which python environment you want to use.

Comment: At firsrt try `pip install numpy` . If this does not work try this ["Import could not be resolved" reported by Pyright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052890/import-could-not-be-resolved-reported-by-pyright)

Comment: my problem is solved

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this in VSCode IDE:

(1) ctrl-shift-p

(2) In search box, type python and then select Python: Select Interpreter

(3) select Python 3.10.4 or any one matches your verion

the problem usually caused by IDE didn't pick up the right interpreter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!

Comment: In case anaconda is used, the base environment might be selected by default instead of your custom one.

Answer (score 5):

For people who use Visual Studio Code: sometimes happens that import could not be resolve because the Python interpreter is not selected.
In this case ctrl + shift + p ---> Select python interpreter --> Python version installed on the computer

Answer (score 2):

I was using two versions of python. Then I uninstalled both versions of it and installed the latest version of python 3.10.1 from https://www.python.org/. After this, installed pip Matplotlib and Numpy.
Everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have installed it in another env

1. Try to change version from python interpreter
2. Try to install python IDE
3. Try to uninstall it and install numpy again

Hope this will fix your issue!!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with *Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance* with `numpy`, `pandas` and `mlflow`. Here is how I resolved it.

My environment is Windows 10 and I have install `python3` on path `c:\python\python.exe`.

When I run:
`which python` in my WSL2 it show `c:\python\python.exe`

So I studied `mlflow` then I have install `Anaconda` [from here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html) and installed `pyenv` then `pip install numpy`.

Everything work well now and when I run `which python` in my WSL2 again it shows `/home/sutee/.local/bin/anaconda3/bin/python`.

I now have `python` on `anaconda3` and `python` on my Windows 10.

The solution for clear warning:

1. I try to change "Python Select Interpreter" but can have only see the one from `C:\python\python.exe` and can't enter path from WSL.
2. I install `numpy`, `pandas` and `mlflow` from Windows environments by using Windows PowerShell in admin and running `pip3.exe`.

Example:

```
C:\python\Scripts\pip3.exe install numpy
C:\python\Scripts\pip3.exe install pandas
C:\python\Scripts\pip3.exe install mlflow
```

After installing each package, the warning is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was simply solved by making the environment a trusted workspace. VS Code had disabled various extensions (including numpy), and had a bar above the workspace but below the search pane.

1. click Manage
2. trust workspace

hope no one else spins their wheels like I did on this one!

Answer (score 0):

Only adding this to the list of possible solutions because it worked for me when nothing else here did.  I did not have `pylint`, `numpy`, or the `matplotlib` extensions installed globally, instead only installing them within my `.venv` environment.  Linting kept reporting both `numpy` and `matplotlib` libraries as unresolved until I disabled VS Code - Global Linting via `Ctrl + Shift + P` => `Python: Enable/Disable Linting` => `Disable`

[image: VS Code Linting]

After that, linting behavior began acting as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me:

```
conda upgrade numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message.

My problem was that, I selected the virtual environment after installing the numpy library.

The issue was resolved when I:

1. Closed the terminal
2. Reinstalled the numpy library

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using VSCode:

- press `F1`,
- then select or write `Developer: Reload Window`