# Pyright couldnt find installed libraries

Tags: python, neovim, pyright

if I type in a file:

```
import numpy
```

pyright will return me an error: `Import "numpy" could not be resolved`

i've seen [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052890/import-could-not-be-resolved-reported-by-pyright)

but i did set the right python version (3.10) where i have numpy installed (i only have python3.10 installed)

runing the program works fine

(im using nvim with lsp, yet runing pyright from the cmd work the same way)
im on windows11

Comment: try to add the environment of site packages in windows path. Type 'C:\Users{Username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python{Python Version}\Lib\site-packages'. This might work for you.

Comment: @BerlinBenilo - i append windows path with my site-packages directory; yet it still showing me the same error