# i am unable to use my extension in my program

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyttsx3

i just completed making an copy of jarvis from iron man for my project but i have encountered some issues with it
I am unable to use it whenever I use it It shows import pyttsx3 could not be resolved
I tried reinstalling it but still I encountered  the same problem please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mc5B.png)

I tried reinstalling it tried different youtube tutorials but i am unable to solve it
I expect someone can help me in it

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052890)

Answer (score 0):

Have you choose the correct python interpreter?

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the correct interpreter which has insatlled these packages.